# PHP socket bind privilege port

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to bind and listen to a privilege port however I keep receiving this message "Permission denied"

Here are the things I have tried to do:

```
chgrp www-data file.php
chmod 770 file.php
```

Gave the file the correct permissions to execute and still nothing

```
setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep file.php
```

Did not work, probably because it is not a executable file...

```
posix_setuid(0)
```

Gave my script root privileges however it did not change the user id for the script. It remained the same.

Comment: What does this program look like? How is it being called? Changing ownership or permissions on a file will not allow it to do things it can't normally do. And if any program could call `posix_setuid(0)` things would be very messy indeed!

Comment: this script is being called by a jquery ajax call, this script is suppose to listen to this port and echo out w/e it listens to but I need the script to bind and listen first. P.S. Hehe yeah things would be very messy if any program could change privileges

Comment: Can you show the command you are using to execute the script?

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding regarding file permissions and the permissions required to execute, in this case bind to a port number lower than 1024.

File permissions only deal with who can read and write to the file. I.e. when you do:

```
chmod 770 file.php
```

You are allowing file.php to rw by owner and group, but no access for users outside the group.

What you need is a privileged user to **execute** the file (root in this case since that is the only account able to bind to privileged ports). However letting PHP anywhere near root is a security risk (outside the scope of this question to elaborate). Since you require root your best bet is allowing the standard (unprivileged) user that runs your web-server obtain a shell with root permissions only when needed. Then trigger your script in this priviliged shell.

Here is a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell as root. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('php /full/path/to/file.php');
```